# Generate Insert Script with If Not Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I created a script for inserting to a table as follows using Task -> generate Script

```
GO
INSERT [USRPT].[Entity] ([DisplayName], [DataTableOrView], [PrimaryColumn], [BasedOn]) 
VALUES ( N'Resource Booking', N'exceViewRptResourceBooking rb', N'rb.BookingId', N'BOK')
GO
INSERT [USRPT].[Entity] ([DisplayName], [DataTableOrView], [PrimaryColumn], [BasedOn]) 
VALUES ( N'Freezed Contracts', N'exceViewRptFreeze fc', N'fc.FreezeItemId', N'FRZ')
GO
INSERT [USRPT].[Entity] ([DisplayName], [DataTableOrView], [PrimaryColumn], [BasedOn]) 
VALUES ( N'Article', N'exceViewRptArticle art', N'art.ArticleId', N'ATL')
GO
```

but i want to do it as follows using scripting tool(because actual data set is large)

```
GO
if not exists (select * from USRPT.Entity where DisplayName = 'Resource Booking')
begin
    INSERT [USRPT].[Entity] ([DisplayName], [DataTableOrView], [PrimaryColumn], [BasedOn]) 
    VALUES (N'Resource Booking', N'exceViewRptResourceBooking rb', N'rb.BookingId', N'BOK')
end

GO
if not exists (select * from USRPT.Entity where DisplayName = 'Freezed Contracts')
begin
    INSERT [USRPT].[Entity] ([DisplayName], [DataTableOrView], [PrimaryColumn], [BasedOn]) 
    VALUES (N'Freezed Contracts', N'exceViewRptFreeze fc', N'fc.FreezeItemId', N'FRZ')
end
GO
if not exists (select * from USRPT.Entity where DisplayName = 'Article')
begin
    INSERT [USRPT].[Entity] ([DisplayName], [DataTableOrView], [PrimaryColumn], [BasedOn]) 
    VALUES (N'Article', N'exceViewRptArticle art', N'art.ArticleId', N'ATL')
end
```

is there any way of doing this using SSMS or any other tool
I want this ti save as a single .sql file and send to client.

Comment: To do that you need to define what is the 'match key' to decide whether the record exists or not. I usually build these kind of scripts in Excel with formulas and stuff but there might be a smarter way to do it by now. If it does not have to be a standalone script you could do this with SSIS or with a INSERT/SELECT

Comment: Oh... the other way is use `MERGE`, where the source of the merge is a bunch of `SELECT UNION` statements. Can you update the tags with the correct **version** of SQL Server so we can suggest suitable solutions?

Comment: thank you for your reply...i have edited the tag and will try with merge..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MERGE` to modify the Entity table by updating and inserting rows.
  When the value of [DisplayName] in the source table matches a value in the [DisplayName]
  column of the target table, (Entity), all the columns are updated in the target table. 
  When the value of [DisplayName] does not match, the source row is inserted into the target table.
  The source table is a derived table that uses the Transact-SQL table value constructor to specify multiple 
  rows for the source table.

```
DECLARE Entity TABLE ([DisplayName] nvarchar(200),
                              [DataTableOrView] nvarchar(200),
                              [PrimaryColumn] nvarchar(200),
                              [BasedOn] nvarchar(200)); 

INSERT into @Entity ([DisplayName], [DataTableOrView], [PrimaryColumn], [BasedOn]) 
VALUES ( N'Resource Booking', N'Test rb', N'Test', N'Test')

MERGE into Entity AS target     
    USING (VALUES (N'Resource Booking', N'exceViewRptResourceBooking rb', N'rb.BookingId', N'BOK'),
                  (N'Freezed Contracts', N'exceViewRptFreeze fc', N'fc.FreezeItemId', N'FRZ'),
                  (N'Article', N'exceViewRptArticle art', N'art.ArticleId', N'ATL'))
    AS source ([DisplayName], [DataTableOrView], [PrimaryColumn], [BasedOn])
    ON (target.[DisplayName] = source.[DisplayName])
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET [DataTableOrView] = source.[DataTableOrView],
                   [PrimaryColumn] = source.[PrimaryColumn],
                   [BasedOn] = source.[BasedOn]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([DisplayName], [DataTableOrView], [PrimaryColumn], [BasedOn])
    VALUES (source.[DisplayName], source.[DataTableOrView], source.[PrimaryColumn], source.[BasedOn] );
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on the fact you have a pre-generated script you want to work with.

One way to achieve this based on a script that you have is to `INSERT` the values into a `#TEMP` table and then `INSERT` into the main table using a `NOT EXISTS` clause.

So first create a temp table above the code:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ([DisplayName] nvarchar(max), 
                    [DataTableOrView] nvarchar(max), 
                    [PrimaryColumn] nvarchar(max), 
                    [BasedOn] nvarchar(max))
```

Then do a mass find and replace on all references of `[USRPT].[Entity]`, replacing it with `#temp`. So your statements would all look like this:

```
INSERT #temp ([DisplayName], [DataTableOrView], [PrimaryColumn], [BasedOn]) 
VALUES ( N'Resource Booking', N'exceViewRptResourceBooking rb', N'rb.BookingId', N'BOK')
```

This will give you a `#temp` table containing all of the records you want to `INSERT` if they don't already exist.

Once that table is created, you can then perform an `INSERT` to the main table like so:

```
INSERT [USRPT].[Entity] ([DisplayName], [DataTableOrView], [PrimaryColumn], [BasedOn])
SELECT [DisplayName], [DataTableOrView], [PrimaryColumn], [BasedOn]
FROM #temp
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT DisplayName 
                    FROM [USRPT].[Entity] m
                    WHERE  m.DisplayName = #temp.DisplayName )
```

So it will `INSERT` records that do not already exist.

A simplified example that you can run to test is below:

```
CREATE TABLE #master ( val VARCHAR(10) )

INSERT  INTO #master
        ( val )
VALUES  ( 'abc' ),
        ( 'def' ),
        ( 'ghi' ),
        ( 'jkl' ),
        ( 'mno' ),
        ( 'pqr' )

SELECT  val AS OriginalValues
FROM    #master

CREATE TABLE #temp ( val VARCHAR(10) )

INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( val )
VALUES  ( 'abc' ),
        ( 'def' ),
        ( 'stu' ),
        ( 'xyz' )

SELECT  val AS ValuesToBeInserted
FROM    #temp

INSERT  INTO #master
        ( val
        )
        SELECT  val
        FROM    #temp
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT val
                             FROM   #master m
                             WHERE  m.val = #temp.val )

SELECT val AS MergedValues 
FROM #master
ORDER BY val

DROP TABLE #master
DROP TABLE #temp
```